# Deciding Which Platforms to Support -- Silveright (+Android?)

Tags: cross-platform

My "usual" stack for game dev is to create (in-browser) Silverlight games. I've decided I want to branch into iPhone or Android, and decided to go droid because it's cheaper (considering I don't have a Mac).

Having now all the requisite software and hardware, **how do I decide which games to code on both platforms and which to not?**

In an ideal world, it would only cost me 5-10% more (time/effort) to port it to Android having developed it for SL. But I know the worst case is 100%+ (i.e. rewrite), and that it'll be somewhere in the middle.

Considering everything will likely be free (although it might be worth it to release the SL one free and offer a $5 paid one on Android, not sure), what are factors to look at?

Comment: How are you going to be "porting" your silverlight games to Android?  Have you looked into something like Unity which allows you to write scripts in C#?

Comment: Also everything I've read is that the Android platform is very similar to the iOS market in that games with in app purchase (i.e. the freemium model) are the most successful.  Do your games have some kind of mechanism that is suitable to that monetization strategy?  I doubt you'll make any money selling a game for $5 a pop.

Comment: @Tetrad my porting mechanism of choice is to use XNA and MonoGame. My engine sits on top of XNA. I don't have a monetization strategy; maybe that's something that should determine whether I create an Android version or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your question "how do I decide which games to code on both platforms and which to not?"  That will be up to you.  Though you will want to look at a not so graphic/physic base games to port over. (High poly count equals a very slow game in android).
Try something simple, and see if it's harder or easier than you thought.